# jaxws-tubes-default.xml missing while consuming SOAP service on appengine (Java)

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine, soap, wsdl

I am building a backend which needs to consume a SOAP service. I generated my sources from the WSDL using wsimport. Upon executing the external service call while handling a request on devserver, I am getting the following. Any suggestions how to resolve the problem?

```
> HTTP ERROR 500
> 
> Problem accessing /hello. Reason:
> 
>     MASM0001: Default configuration file [ jaxws-tubes-default.xml ] was not found
> 
> Caused by:
> 
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: MASM0001: Default configuration file
> [ jaxws-tubes-default.xml ] was not found     at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.MetroConfigLoader.init(MetroConfigLoader.java:127)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.MetroConfigLoader.<init>(MetroConfigLoader.java:104)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblyController.getTubeCreators(TubelineAssemblyController.java:78)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.assembler.MetroTubelineAssembler.createClient(MetroTubelineAssembler.java:103)
>   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.createPipeline(Stub.java:328)
>   at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:295)    at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:228)     at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:243)     at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:84)    at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getStubHandler(WSServiceDelegate.java:814)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:803)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:436)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:404)
>   at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:386)
>   at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)   at
> com.chrome.services.description7b.Description7B.getDescription7BPort(Description7B.java:72)
>   at com.mypackage.appapi.HelloAppEngine.doGet(HelloAppEngine.java:41)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)     at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
> com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>   at
> com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)     at
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>   at
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)  at
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)  at
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)  at
> org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>   at
> org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: However, I just verified that the service can be consumed on appengine, so it appears to be just devserver issue. I would still be interested in a solution though.

Comment: Is `jaxws-tubes-default.xml` missing from your `WEB-INF` project directory?  If not, is there a minimal code/project sample that can be used to reproduce this error?

Comment: If you are no longer affected by this issue, what have you done to resolve it?